# Javascript serializer extra comma

Tags: c#

I am using the Javascript serializer to parse a JSON file.  Its runs fine when the file is in a valid json format but failing for instance there is a extra comma in the last field. How could I bypass that, I am only retrieving the replicateid from this file:

```
{
    "Orders": 
    [
       {
            "Rack": "0014",
            "SampleType": "Calibrator",
            "Replicate": 3,
            "Track": 1,
            "Lane": 2,
            "ReagentMasterLot": "06100AA02",
            "ReagentSerialNumber": "60002",
            "Comment": "HTLV Cal T1L2",
        }
   ]      
}

public static KeyValuePair<bool, int> CyclesCompleted(string fileName)
{
    int cyclesCompleted = 0;
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = jss();
    bool isValid = true;
    try
    {
        CategoryTypeColl ctl = ser.Deserialize<CategoryTypeColl>(LoadTextFromFile(fileName));

        if (ctl != null)
        {
            List<CategoryType> collection = (from item in ctl.orders
                                             select item).ToList();

            foreach (var replicates in collection)
            {
                cyclesCompleted = cyclesCompleted + replicates.Replicate;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        isValid = false;
    }
    return new KeyValuePair<bool, int>(isValid, cyclesCompleted);
}
```

Comment: A trailing comma might be valid in C# object initializers, but it **is not** valid in javascript / JSON. It is hard to argue that this is the fault of the serializer; you should be giving it valid *data*...

Comment: I agree with you, this scenario defeats the whole purpose of a json file, i get these files from an instrument so lets see, i will try json.net library to see if i could get by

Comment: Please see, "[Should language-specific questions contain the language name in the title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-language-specific-questions-contain-the-language-name-in-the-title)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I think the question refers to the [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), in the context of C#, not Javascript.

Comment: The language-specific tag I was referring to was "C#". I have already removed it.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I should have checked.

Comment: Also +1 to the following user answer, if u accepted this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). it is an open source library to serialize and deserialize the .net objects to json string and vice versa. It almost solve these kind of issues which .net json serializiation not.

```
string json = @"{
  ""Name"": ""Apple"",
  ""Expiry"": new Date(1230422400000),
  ""Price"": 3.99,
  ""Sizes"": [
    ""Small"",
    ""Medium"",
    ""Large""
  ]
}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

string name = (string)o["Name"];
// Apple

JArray sizes = (JArray)o["Sizes"];

string smallest = (string)sizes[0];
```

Comment: thats cool, i am trying to use it, are you positive that it will not fuss over an extra comma?

Comment: JSON.NET deserialization works better with more flexibility than the C# one, than you sheihk sahib

Comment: @user1475788 i used JSON.net and it removes these kind of issues that .net does not.